# MS Access compare phone numbers

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database that I pull a table from HR. The HR table has two phone numbers home & cell. My master has three phone numbers home, work & cell. I need a query that will take my 3 numbers and compare it to the 2 HR numbers and only show me employees whose numbers do not match to HR. I need it to know that any of my three could be any of the 2 from HR. HR does not nessecarilly use the correct category for the number (ie: home might be a cell and cell might be work or 2nd cell or emergency contact).

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, 
Employees.Home, Switch([Employees].[Home]=[HR].[Home],"HomeHR",[Employees].[Home]=[HR].[Cell],"CellHR") AS HTest, 
Employees.Work, Switch([Employees].[Work]=[HR].[Home],"HomeHR",[Employees].[Work]=[HR].[Cell],"CellHR") AS WTest, 
Employees.Cell, Switch([Employees].[Cell]=[HR].[Home],"HomeHR",[Employees].[Cell]=[HR].[Cell],"CellHR") AS CTest
FROM HR RIGHT JOIN Employees ON HR.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID;
```

Or

```
SELECT Q1.* FROM (
    SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.Home AS PhoneNum, 
       "Home" AS SrcEmp, Switch([Employees].[Home]=[HR].[Home],"Home",[Employees].[Home]=[HR].[Cell],"Cell") AS SrcHR 
       FROM HR RIGHT JOIN Employees ON HR.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
    UNION SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.Work, 
       "Work", Switch([Employees].[Work]=[HR].[Home],"Home",[Employees].[Work]=[HR].[Cell],"Cell") 
       FROM HR RIGHT JOIN Employees ON HR.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID 
    UNION SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.Cell, 
       "Cell", Switch([Employees].[Cell]=[HR].[Home],"Home",[Employees].[Cell]=[HR].[Cell],"Cell")
       FROM HR RIGHT JOIN Employees ON HR.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID) AS Q1
WHERE SrcEmp<>SrcHR;
```

Or

Query1:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Home AS EmpPhoneNum, "Home" AS SrcEmp FROM Employees
UNION SELECT EmployeeID, Work, "Work" FROM Employees
UNION SELECT EmployeeID, Cell, "Cell" FROM Employees;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Home AS PhoneNumFromHR, "Home" AS SrcHR AS FROM HR
UNION SELECT EmployeeID, Cell, "Cell" FROM HR;
```

Query3:

```
SELECT Query1.EmployeeID, Query1.SrcEmp, Query1.EmpPhoneNum, Query2.PhoneNumFromHR
FROM Query2 RIGHT JOIN Query1 
ON (Query2.SrcHR = Query1.SrcEmp) AND (Query2.PhoneNumFromHR = Query1.EmpPhoneNum) 
AND (Query2.EmployeeID = Query1.EmployeeID)
WHERE (((Query1.SrcEmp)<>"Work") AND ((Query2.PhoneNumFromHR) Is Null));
```